# What is the most efficient data structure to store a list of integers that need to be looked up a lot in .Net?

Tags: data-structures, collections, .net-4.0

I need an efficient data structure to store a list of integers. The amount in the list could range from 1 to probably never more than 1000. The list will be queried about 20 times per request. What would be the most efficient collection type to store these in?

**UPDATE**

To give a little more insight, we'll take [www.wikipediamaze.com (a little game I wrote)](http://www.wikipediamaze.com) as an example (not the real scenario but close enough for conversation). For the list of puzzles on any given page, I am currently returning a list from the puzzles table joined to the table that stores which puzzles the current user has played. Instead I want to cache the list of puzzles agnostic to the user. So what I am doing is first loading and caching the list of puzzles from the database. Then I load and cache the list of puzzles the user has played. Then when I am iterating over the puzzles to display them, I want to do this:

```
protected BestDataStructure<long> PlayedPuzzles {get; set;} //Loaded from session

protected bool HasBeenPlayed(long puzzleId)
{
    return PlayedPuzzles.Contains(puzzleId)
}
```

Whenever they play a new puzzle I will save the record to the database and append it to the list stored in the session.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "queried"?

Comment: I mean searched. I need to look and see if it contains a particular integer about 20 times in a single request.

Comment: There could be one of several solutions. Could you provide a bit more info such as *how* you want to perform the look-up/what information you need to extract? Specifying the range of numbers themselves may also help. Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how you need to query them, but a simple array, or [`HashSet<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) springs to mind.

Both are O(1) when you index into them. HashSet.Contains is also O(1).

**In response to your comment on the question**: Use HashSet, since you need to check whether a specified integer exists. You should use Contains() on HashSet to do this; it will give you the best performance. If you need to store some other value related to the value, perhaps use Dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a structure that efficiently does an operation such as `Contains()`, then `HashSet<int>` is what you're looking for. `HashSet<int>` is O(1) (constant time) for `Contains()`, which is as good a complexity as you're going to get.

Answer (score 1):

[HashSet(int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

if you need to check for presence of element, then probably `bool[]` with 1000 elements and set true for existing integer elements?

Comment: It would need to contain a number of elements equal to the entire range of integer values that are concerned, which could be much larger indeed.

Comment: Yes, sure. Seems that yesterday I was a bit sleepy when answered and mixed 1000 elements with values from 1..1000.